# How to allow ipv6 to a specific port with ufw

Tags: ufw, ipv6

I recently tried to deny all traffic to a specific port, then allowing it only to a specific ipv6 by using

« ufw allow from ipv6 to any port 843 »

But It don’t work, and I dont know why since it works well with ipv4,

the ipv6 option is already enabled in the config.